# send POST data consists array iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development I have to `POST` data in array format

My server side code is

```
$auth_query = array
(
     'User'      =>     array
     ( 
      'username'  =>    'example@example.com',
      'password'  =>    'example'            
    )
);
```

and my api call in Xcode is

```
NSString *urlGetuser =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/login_api.json"];

NSURL *urlProducts=[NSURL URLWithString:urlGetuser];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:urlProducts];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableString *postData = [NSMutableString string];

NSMutableDictionary *user_details = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[user_details setObject:@"example@example.com" forKey:@"username"];

[user_details setObject:@"example" forKey:@"password”];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:user_details forKey:@"User”];

NSString *usr_details = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict];

[postData appendFormat:@"%@",usr_details];

NSData *body = [postData dataUsingEncoding:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

[request setHTTPBody: body];

NSURLResponse *response;

NSError *error;

NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSMutableArray *jsonDATA=(NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

I am not able to spot the issue thanks in advance

Comment: The username you are sending (`@"example.com"`) does not match the username you are expecting `"example@example.com"`.  There might be other problems.  Perhaps you could add additional information to your question that explains what you're seeing as well as what you expect and how those things differ.  It would also help to post server-side logs and HTTP response codes.

Comment: @par Actually the request hit the server in server there is a user named example and I get the response from the else part as the user name password does not match

Comment: OUT Json {
    Message = "Your login credentials do not match. Please login again";
    status = Fail;
}
2016-03-04 10:48:00.615 E[858:23303] Response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x78e4ffa0> { URL: http://e/apis/login_api.json } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 96;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 04 Mar 2016 05:04:56 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.31";
} }

Comment: @par Now when i debug the code in server side the request is posted as username =     {
        "{\n____User_" = "     {\n        password = example;\n        username = \"example@example.com\";\n    };\n}";
    };

Comment: Got it The answer is  NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[arr objectAtIndex:0] options:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Answer (score 0):

Actually for posting method we have different ways  and one of the easiest way, the below code helps to Loads the data for a URL request and executes a handler block on an operation queue when the request completes or fails.

```
 if( [self setParams]){

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:queue
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                                   NSLog(@"image post Completed");

                                   response.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                   [indicator stopAnimating];
                                   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;

                                   if (error) {
                                       NSLog(@"error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
                                   }

                               }];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *username = @“username";
NSString *password = @“password";
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSDictionary *firstJsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: username,@"email",password,@"password", nil];                                     
NSDictionary *secondJsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                             firstJsonDictionary,@"user",                                           nil];
NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObject:secondJsonDictionary];
NSLog(@"Post contents %@",secondJsonDictionary);
NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[arr objectAtIndex:0] options:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
NSString *urlGetuser =[NSString stringWithFormat:@“www.example.com"];
NSURL *urlProducts=[NSURL URLWithString:urlGetuser];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:urlProducts];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData2];
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];


        NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
        if (aData)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *json_DATA = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
            NSLog(@"OUT Json %@",json_DATA);
        }
     [_activityindicator stopAnimating]; 
     _overlayView.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing iOS development, you're starting off with some bad things: 1) you should avoid using synchronous network connections, because they can freeze your app waiting for the response, 2) you should avoid using NSURLConnection in new projects, as the NSURLSession methods will give you more flexibility, and the ability to do background transfers and even Apple Watch connectivity.  To solve all this, get and use the excellent AFNetworking code at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).  No need to rewrite code that other more experienced coders have already written.